# Manipulating JSON messages from Kafka topic using Logstash filter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, filter, apache-kafka, logstash

I am using Logstash 2.4 to read JSON messages from a Kafka topic and send them to an Elasticsearch Index.

The JSON format is as below --

```
{
   "schema":
             {
            "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
                    {
                   "type":"string",
                   "optional":false,
                   "field":"reloadID"
                },
                {
                   "type":"string",
                   "optional":false,
                   "field":"externalAccountID"
                },
                {
                   "type":"int64",
                   "optional":false,
                   "name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
                   "version":1,
                   "field":"reloadDate"
                },
                {
                   "type":"int32",
                   "optional":false,
                   "field":"reloadAmount"
                },
                {
                   "type":"string",
                   "optional":true,
                   "field":"reloadChannel"
                }
              ],
        "optional":false,
        "name":"reload"
         },
   "payload":
             {
            "reloadID":"328424295",
        "externalAccountID":"9831200013",
        "reloadDate":1446242463000,
        "reloadAmount":240,
        "reloadChannel":"C1"
         }
}
```

Without any filter in my config file, the target documents from the ES index look like below --

```
{
  "_index" : "kafka_reloads",
  "_type" : "logs",
  "_id" : "AVfcyTU4SyCFNFP2z5-l",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "schema" : {
      "type" : "struct",
      "fields" : [ {
        "type" : "string",
        "optional" : false,
        "field" : "reloadID"
      }, {
        "type" : "string",
        "optional" : false,
        "field" : "externalAccountID"
      }, {
        "type" : "int64",
        "optional" : false,
        "name" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
        "version" : 1,
        "field" : "reloadDate"
      }, {
        "type" : "int32",
        "optional" : false,
        "field" : "reloadAmount"
      }, {
        "type" : "string",
        "optional" : true,
        "field" : "reloadChannel"
      } ],
      "optional" : false,
      "name" : "reload"
    },
    "payload" : {
      "reloadID" : "155559213",
      "externalAccountID" : "9831200014",
      "reloadDate" : 1449529746000,
      "reloadAmount" : 140,
      "reloadChannel" : "C1"
    },
    "@version" : "1",
    "@timestamp" : "2016-10-19T11:56:09.973Z",
  }
}
```

But, I want only the value part of the "payload" field to move to my ES index as the target JSON body. So I tried to use the 'mutate' filter in the config file as below --

```
input {
   kafka {
            zk_connect => "zksrv-1:2181,zksrv-2:2181,zksrv-4:2181"
            group_id => "logstash"
            topic_id => "reload"
            consumer_threads => 3
   }
}
filter {
  mutate {
     remove_field => [ "schema","@version","@timestamp" ]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["datanode-6:9200","datanode-2:9200"]
                    index => "kafka_reloads"
   }
}
```

With this filter, the ES documents now look like below --

```
{
      "_index" : "kafka_reloads",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "AVfch0yhSyCFNFP2z59f",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "payload" : {
          "reloadID" : "850846698",
          "externalAccountID" : "9831200013",
          "reloadDate" : 1449356706000,
          "reloadAmount" : 30,
          "reloadChannel" : "C1"
        }
      }
}
```

But actually It should be like below --

```
{
      "_index" : "kafka_reloads",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "AVfch0yhSyCFNFP2z59f",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
          "reloadID" : "850846698",
          "externalAccountID" : "9831200013",
          "reloadDate" : 1449356706000,
          "reloadAmount" : 30,
          "reloadChannel" : "C1"
      }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Can anyone help me on this?

I also tried the below filter --

```
filter {
   json {
      source => "payload"
   }
}
```

But that is giving me errors like --

Error parsing json {:source=>"payload", :raw=>{"reloadID"=>"572584696", "externalAccountID"=>"9831200011", "reloadDate"=>1449093851000, "reloadAmount"=>180, "reloadChannel"=>"C1"}, :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyHash cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyIO, :level=>:warn}

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Gautam Ghosh

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you want using the following `ruby` filter:

```
  ruby {
     code => "
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k != 'payload'}
        event.to_hash.update(event['payload'].to_hash)
        event.to_hash.delete_if {|k, v| k == 'payload'}
     "
  }
```

What it does is:

1. remove all fields but the `payload` one
2. copy all `payload` inner fields at the root level
3. delete the `payload` field itself

You'll end up with what you need.

Comment: Excellent!! That worked perfectly.. thanks a lot buddy!!

Comment: Great stuff, thanks @Val. This will be of lots of use to anyone using Oracle GoldenGate -> Kafka -> Logstash ->

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I'm glad if this is useful to you. Since I've been using this code in several contexts, I'm considering creating a logstash filter out of it. I'll update this thread whenever I do it. I'm just not yet sure how to call it. Any idea?

Comment: Or I could simply amend the existing `mutate` filter with another `extract` operation maybe. Not sure about the name of that operation though...

Comment: @RobinMoffatt if my pull request is accepted it will soon be easier to do the same thing using `mutate/copy`: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/new-operation-for-the-mutate-filter/75070

Comment: @Val Great, hope it gets accepted. In the meantime you saved me a bunch of manual work, thank you :)

Comment: Hi Val, I have recently migrated to Logstash 5.4.1 and the above solution ceased to work :( Do I need to make any changes to the Ruby filter code?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/issues/90#issuecomment-456873938) there is a valid workaround, hope it would be useful.

```
json_encode {
  source => "json"
  target => "json_string"
}

json {
  source => "json_string"
}
```

Comment: another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61387147/817037